# logging in c++ (performance considerations)

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, logging

I am new to cpp (come from Java).
I am writing a cpp application. The application is performance critical.
i looked for a logging framework and i found [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)
at the end of the linked above there is performance section that explain:

> When logging is turned off entirely or just for a set of levels, the
>   cost of a log request consists of a method invocation plus an integer
>   comparison

I remember from old days in university that we used then with `#ifndf` to wrap logging.

Questions:

1. Is wrapping logging with `#ifndf` is still standard practice?
2. Is there is something similar to the following pseudo-code?

```
logger.Log_Debug(() => { "My complicated log message " + thisFunctionTakesALongTime() + " will take no time" });
```

Comment: I'm not using C++ in a professional sense, but in the languages where I do work, turning logging off at *build* time would be a big no-no; you could never turn it back up when you *need* it.

Comment: `#ifdef` is a compile time switch. log4cxx, and other logging frameworks like [boost.log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) use a runtime switch to enable disable logging. When something goes wrong in production you don't want to have to reconfigure, rebuild and and redeploy just to enable logging...

Comment: Remus, i am aware to it, but debug code shouldnt be part of my release due to performance (thousands of check level in a seconds) and due to security.

Comment: Well, checking a boolean is pretty quick:) I do understand the security issue, though.  Looks like you're stuck with two builds - one for release and one to send to the customers who have problems.  During a beta test, this will probably be all of them <g>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own macro that does nothing when in release mode:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG(x) logger.Log_Debug(x)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG(x)
#endif
```

Comment: I know. this is my question if its still a common practice?

Comment: @user1495181 yes, if you require it. but the above should be `#define LOG_DEBUG(x) ((void)x)` for release, in case invocation of `x` has valuable side effects.

Comment: I still don't consider these macros acceptable. The main issue now is that you will get spurious warnings (`x` is unused) if you do `int x = some_function(); if (x==0) LOG_DEBUG("some function returned zero");`. But at least they're not broken.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a macro that compiles logging out conditionally is not equivalent to turning it off and on at runtime. Of course if you turn off logging with conditional compile, you will save on method invocation, but you wouldn't be able to turn the logging back on at will.

One solution that lets you save on the method invocation would be to wrap logging in a macro with an `if` statement that checks if the logging is enabled, and skips over the invocation if it is not enabled. This will save you a cost of invocation, which in most cases is going to be more expensive than a simple condition check:

```
#define LOG(X) if(logger.is_enabled) do {logger.log(X);}while(0)
```

If `logger.log` has several overloads, you may need to define a separate macro for each set of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you `boost::logging`. http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html but now it's not a part of boost.
And `#ifdef` is common practice, if you don't need logging in release version.

Answer (score 0):

https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/usage.html:

**Logging performance when logging is turned off.**

When logging is turned off entirely or just for a set of levels, the cost of a log request consists of a method invocation plus an integer comparison. The LOG4CXX_DEBUG and similar macros suppress unnecessary expression evaluation if the request is not enabled.